# UIRefreshControl after 3 seconds endRefreshing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a function that updates a `UITableView` by using `UIRefreshControl`. But I want that it after 3 second the function call `EndRefreshing`.

```
func updateMyTable(){

    tableView.reloadData()

    //refreshTable.endRefreshing()  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best delay method I know available on swift:

```
func dispatchDelay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Your code will be:

```
func updateMyTable(){
    tableView.reloadData()
    dispatchDelay(3.0) {
       self.refresh.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

### Update Swit 3:

```
func dispatchDelay(delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay, execute: closure)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the method after some delay using following :

```
self.performSelector(Selector(yourMethod), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 3)
```

The method will call after 3 sec delay. So Add this line where you are updating your table.

Hope it helps..